# Local data store (Pinning) not working with Parse

Tags: parse-platform

I use Parse through Cocoapods.
I call Parse.enableLocalDatastore() before setAppId
I pin an object with this query that returns success = true

```
self.pinInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in
                if success{
                    print("ok")
                }
                else{
                    print("error")
                }
            })
```

I try to retrieve the object with the following :

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Movie")
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if let movies = objects as? [Movie]{
            print(movies.count)
            if movies.count == 0{
                //Update
            }
        }
    }
```

It always returns 0.

I am subclassing PFObject with PFSubclassing protocol with the following :

```
class Movie: PFObject,PFSubclassing {

@NSManaged var title:String
@NSManaged var movieId:NSNumber
@NSManaged var popularity:NSNumber
@NSManaged var poster_path:String
@NSManaged var vote:NSNumber

override class func initialize() {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        self.registerSubclass()
    }
}

static func parseClassName() -> String {
    return "Movie"
}
```

}

Do you have any clue? Thank you.

Comment: It is working well without a custom class. I tried with PFObject(className : "Test") and it worked. Anything wrong in my subclassing ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

I was using selectKeys() in order to retrieve only what was necessary. It probably deactivates pinning for object not fully fetched.